# $S$ be the number of places in a row where a boy and a girl are standing next to each other. What is the average value of $S$ on a given criteria?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that $7$ boys and $13$ girls line up in a row. Let $S$ be the number of places in the row where a boy and a girl are standing next to each other. For example, for the row

$$GBBGGGBGBGGGBGBGGBGG$$

we have $S=12$. If all possible orders of these $20$ people are considered, what is the average value of $S$? Generalize this result to a group of $m$ boys and $n$ girls.

I can find the number of ways in which the boys and girls can be arranged, $\dfrac{20!}{7!13!}$

But, the problem is, I cannot find $S$ for each of this case. This problem looks insane, but maybe there is an easy solution. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You invented the problem or is it a homework or what is the source of the problem?

Comment: It is a problem from a problem book of standard 9 olympiad level.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is standard 9

Comment: You can always write a program to find out.  It will be easier.  But since it is a olympiad problem, it should have a definite closed form solution.

Comment: class 9. and i am supposed to solve it by hand, not by computers.

Answer (score 0):

The following considerations might help.

As example observe the case where $S=4$. Start with $GBGBG$ and $BGBGB$. A minimal
number of persons have been placed and in both cases we have $S=4$.
Observe option $GBGBG$. $10$ girls are yet to be placed. That means
a split up of $10$ as a sum of $3$ nonnegative integers so there
are $\binom{12}{2}=66$ possibilities ([stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))). One of them
is $GGGBGGGGGGBGGGG$. Now the remaining $5$ boys must be placed,
asking for a split up of $5$ as a sum of $2$ nonnegative integers
and resulting in $\binom{6}{1}=6$ possibilities. This because boys are only allowed to be placed next to boys in order to maintain $S=4$. Likewise option
$BGBGB$ can be treated.

This way you can find how much of the possibilities lead to $S=s$ and so come to an expectation of $S$.